# How to select a folder only by using common dialog control

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

Code.

```
CommonDialog1.DialogTitle = "Open File"
CommonDialog1.Filter = "*.*"
CommonDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
CommonDialog1.Flags = cdlOFNAllowMultiselect + cdlOFNExplorer
CommonDialog1.Flags = cdlOFNFileMustExist + cdlOFNHideReadOnly
CommonDialog1.CancelError = True
On Error Resume Next
CommonDialog1.ShowOpen
If Err Then
    'MsgBox "Select Folder"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

From the above code, i am selecting a file, But i don't want to select a file, I want to select only the folder. How to modify my code.

Need vb6 code Help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been a while since I've had to do any visual basic work but I think instead of using the common dialog box for getting the name of a file to open you should use the **SHBrowseForFolder** function which is already part of the Windows API.  Here's a [link](http://www.base64.co.uk/shbrowseforfolder.html) to a page that describes it's usage.

Update (2017): Provided link is broken but [a backed-up version can be viewed on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20081204022345/http://www.base64.co.uk:80/shbrowseforfolder.html)

Comment: Don't do that. Answer should be self contained and not reliant on an external links as they can break over the years. A link can be given as a reference to enrich your answer but should not constitute the main body of it.

Comment: Anyone wanting to see the unbroken link can click here: https://web.archive.org/web/20081204022345/http://www.base64.co.uk:80/shbrowseforfolder.html

Comment: This version seems to be nice: [https://github.com/badcodes/vb6/tree/master/FolderBrowser](https://github.com/badcodes/vb6/tree/master/FolderBrowser)

Comment: @thebunnyrules - The answer is self contained. Had the sentence containing the link not been there the answer would still make sense and inform the user of the action needed to correct the problem.

Answer (score 8):

To select a folder, you can use the Shell and Automation Component.

```
Private shlShell As Shell32.Shell
Private shlFolder As Shell32.Folder
Private Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = &H1

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    If shlShell Is Nothing Then
        Set shlShell = New Shell32.Shell
    End If
    Set shlFolder = shlShell.BrowseForFolder(Me.hWnd, "Select a Directory", BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS)
    If Not shlFolder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox shlFolder.Title
    End If
End Sub
```

You will need to add a reference to `shell32.dll` to your project. Use the Project/References... menu and then browse for `shell32.dll`.

Or you can use the Windows API as Twotymz suggests.

Comment: this works reasonably well, but the shlFolder.Title value is only the selected directory name and not the entire path.

Comment: @KenForslund: I presume that you can retrieve something else on that `shlFolder`object besides `Title` that is more suitable.

Comment: doesn't appear so.  .ParentFolder is the next folder name up, but again, just a simple single name, not a path of any kind. This still solved my need for the moment, but I was expecting a more robust path.

Comment: If you want the full path: `shlFolder.self.Path`

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread, but maybe someone will be helped by this.
This code works in VB6 for me:

```
Private Sub ChooseDir_Click()
    Dim sTempDir As String
    On Error Resume Next
    sTempDir = CurDir    'Remember the current active directory
    CommonDialog1.DialogTitle = "Select a directory" 'titlebar
    CommonDialog1.InitDir = App.Path 'start dir, might be "C:\" or so also
    CommonDialog1.FileName = "Select a Directory"  'Something in filenamebox
    CommonDialog1.Flags = cdlOFNNoValidate + cdlOFNHideReadOnly
    CommonDialog1.Filter = "Directories|*.~#~" 'set files-filter to show dirs only
    CommonDialog1.CancelError = True 'allow escape key/cancel
    CommonDialog1.ShowSave   'show the dialog screen

    If Err <> 32755 Then    ' User didn't chose Cancel.
        Me.SDir.Text = CurDir
    End If

    ChDir sTempDir  'restore path to what it was at entering
End Sub
```

Comment: By using this code user should enter a name for a file that will return a FileName with an extension of `~#~` and also this will go inside the folder by selecting Open button and without entering a name it will not work ;).

Comment: This works almost well. Will retrieve the full path plus string "Select a Directory" or whatever string the user write there. A workaround can be "remove the last part till \" and will work as intended. But I prefer the @Robert Harvey method.

Answer (score -1):

I though that is more general VBA question anyway, opening select folder dialog in VBA for Office >=2k3.

I could not believe that it is so hard, as I need same functionality. Little googling made it.
Here is nice simple solution [take a look](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=896)

```
Function GetFolderName()
    Dim lCount As Long

    GetFolderName = vbNullString
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = OpenAt
        .Show
        For lCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            GetFolderName = .SelectedItems(lCount)
        Next lCount
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: The question is about VB6, not about VBA!, There is not any `Application.FileDialog` in VB6 ;).