# checking format to a text box

Tags: vb6

I need a method to check the contents of the text entered to make sure they are correctly entering a folder path. So it needs to be in the format of:

Drive Letter :\ Folder

e.g. C:\My Documents

If they haven't typed in that format I need to stop and show a message telling them to double check.

I have tried the Filter function but I haven't quite got it to work. Any help would be awesome. I don't have any code to show because I am nto sure where to start.

I also tried the common dialog, but the user jsut needs the type the path, not select the file. All I want to check is if the text type is within that format DRIVE:\FOLDER, that is it. So if the type "BLAH" in the text bax a message says Hey you type a correct path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a folder only by using common dialog control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584045/how-to-select-a-folder-only-by-using-common-dialog-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of implemeting the common dialog control to allow the selection of a correct folder instead - it'll be much more likely to be accurate.

Some example code of folder browsing from [here](http://www.bigresource.com/VB-Customizing-BrowseForFolder-in-VB-2QTFa2T228.html#UpLbM6eQjP):

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0
    Const NO_OPTIONS = 0
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(WINDOW_HANDLE, "select folder:", NO_OPTIONS, "C:Scripts")
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    objPath = objFolderItem.Path
    objPath = Replace(objPath, "", "\")
    Print objPath
End Sub
```

Comment: That might work for the first text box. What I have is the user will specify the folder they want to copy in txtSource, then specify the destination of that folder txtDest. So can I use the common dialog control for both to verify that they are using correct format?

Comment: No the common dialog box will not work. The user doesn't need to search for the file. Once the user defines the source and destination those variables are put into a RoboCopy to copy over the folder, permissions, and tree structure. All I want is to verify that the format is correct for what they type in.

Comment: There is a folder version of the common dialog - just does folder selection and even allows to create new - it just returns strings for the paths involved. I'll have a look to see if I can find some code.

Comment: Am adding some code to my answer. Its not actually common dialog, but a similar functionality.

Comment: Better to use the actual hWnd of the Form than to pass a null handle though.  Actual Options values are useful too.

Comment: @Bob - I've got some production code for this around somewhere but I couldn't find it in a hurry, so the example was a cut and paste example. Production code includes the callback you can use to set the default path.

Answer (score 2):

In VB6, to test whether your text contains a valid folder:

```
If Len(Dir("c:\My Documents", vbDirectory))>0 Then
    'it's a folder
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could validate the folder first you could check for `":\"` using `eith` instr or mid
then you could validate the folder and even include an option to create it if not present with the `filesystemobject` (needs a reference set) here it is in function form, you can pass the contents of the `textbox` for validation.

```
Function DirExists(pFile As String, Optional pCreate As Boolean = False)
'
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim vPath As Variant
Dim sPath As String
Dim y As Variant
DirExists = False
If fso.FolderExists(pFile) Then
    DirExists = True
Else
    If pCreate Then
        vPath = Split(pFile, "\")
        For Each y In vPath
            sPath = sPath & y & "\"
            If Not fso.FolderExists(sPath) Then
                fso.CreateFolder (sPath)
                If fso.FolderExists(pFile) Then
                    DirExists = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End If
End Function
```